# Somar numeros de uma array

Tags: php, array

Estou usando um loop para mostrar todas as respostas de uma respectiva coluna do meu bd. Mas eu preciso somar todos os números contidos nesse array.

Código que estou usando:

```
<?php 

$host = "xxx";
$db   = "xxx";
$user = "xxx";
$pass = "xxx";

// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);

// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT totalPrice, Time FROM deposits ORDER BY Time ASC");

// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());

// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);

// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Investimentos</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {
?>
            <p><?=$linha['totalPrice']?>$</p>
<?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if 
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
```

o resultado dessa array é assim:

```
120$

-100$

400$

-150$

500$

-460$

100$

-290$

100$

-295$

120$

180$

-600$

-700$

-100$

1200$

100$

-200$

100$

600$

-120$
```

Preciso que aqui no final fique o valor total da soma desses números, alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: Deivid, reverti a última edição da sua pergunta pois a ideia aqui é manter a pergunta original. Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma variável que receba a soma do array, por exemplo:

```
int somaTotal;

somaTotal = somaTotal + atoi(linha[Indice])
```

Algo do tipo, usei atoi que é uma função em C que transforma char em inteiro.

Tente assim:

```
$host = "xxx";
$db   = "xxx";
$user = "xxx";
$pass = "xxx";

$somaTotal = 0.0;

// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT totalPrice, Time FROM deposits ORDER BY Time ASC");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Investimentos</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {
?>
            $somaTotal += (float)$linha['totalPrice'];
<?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if 
       print $somaTotal;
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
```

Comment: como fazer isso? eu nao sei.

Comment: Editei o post, tente usar o codigo que alterei. O que falta é mostrar na tela a somaTotal

Comment: não funcionou. eu alterei um pouco buscando um resultado melhor e quase foi, mas ainda sim nao consegui. <? $somaTotal += (int)$linha['totalPrice']; ?> mostrou o resultado redondo, sem somar os centavos.

Comment: Altere para <? $somaTotal += (float)$linha['totalPrice']; ?> Assim os centavos serão somados. Se tiver alguma duvida é so falar

Comment: Isso quer dizer que você precisa definir a variavel antes do loop. por exemplo:

$somaTotal = 0.0 Talvez ela esteja sendo inicializada com 0, inicie com 0.0 que indica que haverá decimais

Comment: Ficou perfeito. Tem alguma forma de agradecer, pontuar? E como faço pra postar o resultado de como ficou pra que pessoas com o mesmo problema vejam o código final.

Comment: Sim, é so clicar no triangulo cinza acima do 0  no post para pontuar. Você pode editar o meu post mesmo, colocando o codigo final que resolveu o seu problema.

Comment: Pra cliclar no triangulo eu preciso ter 15 de feedback, mas ja arrumei o codigo da forma que funcionou. obrigado pelas instruções.

Comment: Legal. Estamos aqui pra isso :)

Comment: @Rafael, em PHP não se preocupe em converter char para tipos numéricos, ele [já faz isso pra você](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Que facilidade, não sabia disso, pois sou programador C.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o `array_sum` exemplo:

No `PHP`:

```
$array = array(150,500,460,100,-290,100, 295,120,180,600,700,100,1200,100,200,100,600,-120);

echo array_sum($array);

 /*retorna a soma do array. se você informar o indice $linha['totalPrice']
 ira somar apenas os valores do indice TotalPrice */
```

No `Mysql`:

```
    SELECT SUM(nome_coluna) AS valor_soma FROM nome_tabela;
```

Você pode até somar outras colunas...

```
 SELECT SUM(nome_coluna1 + nome_coluna2) AS valor_total_soma FROM nome_tabela;
```

No `Php` fica assim:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(nome_coluna1) AS valor_soma FROM nome_tabela'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['valor_soma '];
```

Comment: a primeira opção não da, pq eu não tenho os valores, eles são variáveis, os valores sao do sql, que alteram todo momento. A terceira opção nao se encaixa, como vc pode ver no exemplo, tem apenas 1 tabela que cria um loop.

Comment: faz um var_dum($var) no resultado do mysql e edita sua resposta com o array que você recebe que eu melhoro minha resposta